# ADO.NET calling T-SQL Stored Procedure causes a SqlTimeoutException

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado.net, timeout, output-parameter

I have a T-SQL stored procedure with the signature

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
@recordCount INT OUTPUT
@param1 INT
...
```

When executed directly in Sql Server the procedure runs in under 5 seconds, returning a few result sets amounting to about 100 rows in total.

Calling this procedure using the ADO.NET `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` method to populate a `Dataset` causes a `SqlTimeoutException` on the `SqlCommand` after 3 minutes (the specified timeout interval).

Changing the stored procedure so that it no longer has an output parameter, and that the output value required is returned as the last result set, solves the problem, and the whole thing runs in under 5 seconds as expected.

But why?

I don't want to go through my code base and modify all instances of this type of behaviour without understanding if I have really solved the problem.

Another thing to note is this is only apparent on one particular server, which admittedly has a larger dataset than other similar databases we run. Surely not a Sql Server setting?

**UPDATE**

Stepping into the framework source the issue appears to be in metadata retrieval. The `ConsumeMetaData` method of the `SqlDataReader` object hangs indefinitely. However I ran tests on other databases and cannot reproduce, so it is a database specific issue when this procedure is called though ADO.NET... Great.

**UPDATE II**

Have confirmed the issue still occurs if I change the code to use the `OleDbDataAdapter` with the SQLOLEDB or SQLNCLI provider types. Definitely to do with the connection.

Comment: Does this work if you use a datareader? Have you looked at sql profiler while its stuck in the sqldataadapter.fill?

Comment: Same deal with a SqlDataReader. Have profiled it as well. Interactively I see it takes under 5 seconds duration, exact same call through ADO.NET the profiler shows its takes the timeout duration (180000ms). The Fill method is hanging and holding on to the connnection until it times out.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Once I determined that it is the ADO.NET connection at the root of the problem, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250713/sqldataadapter-fill-method-slow) led me to the answer.

Basically connections through Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) by default have SET `ARITHABORT ON`. ADO.NET connections do not.

Setting `ARITHABORT OFF` and executing the query directly through SSMS gives me the same slow response time.

The main difference when running with or without this setting is a different query plan is created for the two calls. When `ARITHABORT` was `OFF`, the SSMS command would use the pre-compiled cached query plan that the ADO.NET connection was using, and therefore timeout.

By running the following commands as administrator on the database all queries run as expected regardless of the `ARITHABORT` setting.

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

I can only assume a compiled query plan became corrupt, or invalid.

I will go with this as the solution (I have up-voted the answer) on the other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250713/sqldataadapter-fill-method-slow)

Thanks.

Comment: **Warning** This answer is only an extremely short term fix and completely unnecessarily brutal. `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` will drop most of the data pages from cache and have **no effect**. `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` will flush the entire procedure cache all just to remove one problematic plan! There is no guarantee that the problem won't reoccur at some future stage. The issue is parameter sniffing. Please see [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) for fuller explanation.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I've read through that article, and had a pretty hard time really grokking it. Can you provide an explanation for what people can do to fix this issue without running these two lines of code, and what people can do to avoid letting this happen in the future?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior another good article here that discusses a variety of possible preventative measures http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options

Comment: use **WITH RECOMPILE;** on stored procedure. READ: http://sqladvice.com/blogs/gstark/archive/2008/02/12/Arithabort-Option-Effects-Stored-Procedure-Performance.aspx

Comment: WITH RECOMPILE is not a good option for a sproc.  That's going to add overhead every time you call it.

Best to fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

I stand corrected - yes, you **CAN** have both - an OUTPUT parameter as well as a set of rows being returned. You learn something new every day :-)

As to why a timeout happens - hmm.... hard to tell. A quickie little sample works fine for me. Can you post your stored proc (at least relevant bits of it)?

How many rows are we talking about, that get returned here?

At what point in your stored proc are you calculating the number of rows that you need to return back as OUTPUT parameter?

What if you try to add another parameter `MaxRows` to your one SProc as a test and do a `SELECT TOP (@MaxRows).......` on your data? Does that return quickly?

Marc

Comment: Are you sure about this, I could swear Ive used output params with result sets before

Comment: As I said I runs interactively no problem.

Comment: @marc_s

As question states, roughly 100 rows being returned (i.e. minimal). Again as question states, this all works interactively in a few seconds. Only when called though ADO.NET do we get the issue. The procedure is functioning fine, unless you call it though ADO.NET to populate a DataSet.

I am stepping through the source code for SqlDataAdapter.Fill to see where/why it hangs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In short - I fixed my issue by forcing SQL Server to use the most appropriate index to limit lob logical reads when it couldn't figure it out on its own.

In long -

I just ran into this issue and resolved it in a different way after trying all of the other suggested answers.  In SSMS the query was running in ~3s, but was timing out when called from a .Net MVC web application.

Statistics IO output in SSMS was telling me that there were over 195,500,000 lob logical reads on one table (20M-row table with a clustered columnstore index and also has row indexes, but has no "LOB" columns).  I noticed from the execution plan that a bulk of the load (76%) was coming from an index seek on one of the row indices.  I used the following:

```
from [table] with (index([clustered columnstore index name]))
```

in my query to force the usage of the clustered columnstore index and my query was reduced to <1s and the lob logical reads dropped to <6k from >195M, and when calling the SP from the web app now, it is round-tripping in 1.3s.

I tried option recompile, set arithabort on, parameter sniffing, and in the end SQL Server just couldn't figure out which index to use.  This is an edge case too btw, and the only time I have had to force an index in this database.