# Query taking longer in C# than SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a Stored Procedure that takes roughly a second to execute, however, using the same parameters when I deploy it on .NET C#, I reach the part where I use an SqlAdapter and use the Fill function, (using debug mode) I press F11 and then it stays there for like a minute until it finally returns a datatable, which only has one row by the way.

Is there something that I must consider when using C# for an SP instead of SQL?

The query in particular is the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GAS_consumptions_spFullSearchA] 
(
    @idClient INT, 
    @beginDate DATETIME, 
    @endDate DATETIME, 
    @description VARCHAR(1000), 
    @department VARCHAR(50), 
    @area VARCHAR(50), 
    @idCardType INT, 
    @idProduct INT, 
    @idStation INT, 
    @cardCode VARCHAR(16), 
    @idCostCenter INT, 
    @idSection INT, 
    @idDivision INT, 
    @isManual INT, 
    @idInvoice INT
) 
AS 

SET @description = ISNULL(@description, '') 

SELECT DISTINCT 
    con.idConsumption, 
    cli.idClient, 
    ISNULL(cli.tradename, cli.commercialName) AS tradeName, 
    con.quantity, 
    pro.[description], 
    (con.price + con.iepsPerLiter + (con.price * con.tax) / 100) AS price, 
    (con.subtotal + con.ieps) AS subtotal, 
    con.createdDate AS dateCreated, 
    ISNULL(sta.shortname, 'Corporativo') AS name, 
    ISNULL(nip.idCard, nip2.[idCard]) AS idCard, 
    ISNULL(clc.[name], 'CONSUMO ADMIN.') AS contact, 
    '' AS operationType, 
    con.gasPump, 
    con.tax, 
    con.total, 
    sta.idStation, 
    sta.[name] AS stationName, 
    sta.rfc, 
    con.stationSaleNumber, 
    SUBSTRING (ISNULL(car.cardCode, car2.[cardCode]), 9, 16) AS cardCode, 
    ISNULL (veh.economicNumber, veh2.economicNumber) AS economicNumber, 
    ISNULL (veh.model, veh2.model) AS model, 
    ISNULL (veh.licensePlates, veh2.licensePlates) AS licensePlates, 
    sta.pemexKey, 
    pro.idPemex, 
    con.isManual, 
    mcd.comments, 
    rmc.reasonName, 

    CASE 
        WHEN car.cardCode IS NULL THEN 'Tarjeta' 
        ELSE 'CHEQUE' 
    END AS operation, 

    con.TaxAmount, 
    '1' AS RowType, 
    con.CommissionsAmount, 
    con.notes, 
    con.CommissionsValue, 
    con.CommissionsTaxAmount, 
    cat.[description] AS [type], 

    CASE ISNULL(ico.idInvoice, '-1') 
        WHEN -1 THEN '-1' 
        ELSE cor.series + ' ' + CAST(ico.idInvoice AS NVARCHAR) 
    END AS idInvoice, 

    con.mileage, 
    con.stationSaleNumber AS saleNumber, 
    con.workSchedule AS Turno, 
    ISNULL(car.area, car2.area) AS Area, 
    ISNULL(car.department, car2.department) AS department, 

    CASE ISNULL(ico.idInvoice, '-1') 
        WHEN -1 THEN '-1' 
        ELSE inv.series + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(inv.number AS VARCHAR),6) 
    END AS seriesNumber, 

    CASE ISNULL(con.requestedAmount, '') 
        WHEN '' THEN 0 
        ELSE con.requestedAmount 
    END AS RequestAmount, 

    (
        SELECT cup.serial + CAST(cup.folio AS VARCHAR)+ '($' + CAST(cup.amount AS VARCHAR) + ')  ' 
        FROM CCARD_coupon AS cup 
        WHERE cup.IdConsumption = con.idConsumption 
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS couponConsumtion, 

    ISNULL(con.couponConsumption, 0) AS couponConsumption, 
    ISNULL(coce.name, '') AS costCenter, 
    ISNULL(sec.name, '') AS section, 
    ISNULL(div.name, '') AS division, 

    CASE ISNULL(con.isManual, 0) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'MANUAL' 
        ELSE cat.[description] 
    END AS [transaction], 

    CASE con.isManual 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'SI' 
        ELSE '' 
    END AS [Manual], 

    CASE ISNULL(ico.idInvoice, '-1') 
        WHEN -1 THEN '' 
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, inv.createdDate, 120) 
    END AS fechaFactura, 

    cntCls.description AS clasificacion, 
    cntSeg.description AS segmentacion, 
    cntEco.description AS giro, 

    CASE 
        WHEN cct.idClientType IS NULL THEN 'NA' 
        ELSE cct.description 
    END AS tipoCliente, 

    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cli.createdDate, 120) AS clienteCreacion, 
    repBilling.name AS RepFacturacion, 
    repSales.name AS RepVentas, 
    repFinance.name AS RepCobranza, 
    cor.idCorporative, 
    con.picture, 
    con.signature, 

    CAST
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN 
            (
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(con.picture, ''))) = '' 
                AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(con.signature, ''))) = ''
            ) THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END AS BIT
    ) AS imagesAvailable, 

    CAST
    (
        CASE LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(con.picture, ''))) 
            WHEN '' THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END AS BIT
    ) AS pictureAvailable,  

    CAST
    (
        CASE LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(con.signature, ''))) 
            WHEN '' THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END AS BIT
    ) AS signatureAvailable 
FROM 
    GAS_consumptions con WITH(NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN GAS_products pro WITH(NOLOCK) ON pro.IdProduct = con.IdProduct 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GAS_oneTimeNips otn WITH(NOLOCK) ON otn.idOneTimeNip = con.idOneTimeNip 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [GAS_cardNips] nip2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON nip2.[idNip] = otn.[idNip] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GAS_CardNips nip WITH(NOLOCK) ON nip.idNip = con.idNip 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GAS_ClientContacts clc WITH(NOLOCK) ON clc.idClientContact = nip.idClientContact 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GAS_Cards car WITH(NOLOCK) ON car.idCard = nip.idCard 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [GAS_cards] car2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON car2.[idCard] = nip2.[idCard] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [GAS_cardTypes] cat WITH(NOLOCK) ON cat.[idCardType] = car.[idCardType] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CCARD_stations sta WITH(NOLOCK) ON sta.idStation = con.idStation 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GAS_Vehicles veh2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON veh2.idVehicle = car2.idVehicle 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GAS_Vehicles veh WITH(NOLOCK) ON veh.idVehicle = car.idVehicle 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CCARD_clients cli WITH(NOLOCK) ON cli.idClient = con.idClient 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CCARD_clientCreditTypes cct WITH(NOLOCK) ON cct.idClientType = dbo.GetClientType(cli.idAccountType, cli.remissionType, cli.isPayToCard, cli.isCoupon) 
    INNER JOIN CCARD_corporatives cor WITH(NOLOCK) ON cor.idCorporative = cli.idCorporative 
    LEFT OUTER  JOIN GAS_invoiceConsumptions ico WITH(NOLOCK) ON ico.idConsumption = con.idConsumption 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GAS_invoices inv WITH(NOLOCK) ON inv.idInvoice = ico.idInvoice 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GAS_manualConsumptionDetail mcd WITH(NOLOCK) ON mcd.idConsumption = con.idConsumption 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GAS_reasonsManualConsumption rmc WITH(NOLOCK) ON rmc.idReason = mcd.idReasonManualConsumption 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CCARD_divisions div WITH(NOLOCK) ON div.idDivision = con.idDivision 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CCARD_sections sec WITH(NOLOCK) ON sec.idSection = div.idSection 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CCARD_costCenters coce WITH(NOLOCK) ON coce.idCostCenter = sec.idCostCenter 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CCARD_ClientsClassifications cntCls WITH(NOLOCK) ON cntCls.idClientClassification = cli.idClientClassification 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CCARD_ClientsSegmentations cntSeg WITH(NOLOCK) ON cntSeg.idClientSegmentation = cli.idClientSegmentation 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CCARD_clientsEconomicActivities cntEco WITH(NOLOCK) ON cntEco.idEconomicActivity = cli.idEconomicActivity 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PORTA_employees repSales WITH(NOLOCK) ON repSales.idEmployee = cli.salesRepresentative 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PORTA_employees repBilling WITH(NOLOCK) ON repBilling.idEmployee = cli.billingRepresentative 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PORTA_employees repFinance WITH(NOLOCK) ON repFinance.idEmployee = cli.financeRepresentative 
WHERE 
    con.idClient = @idClient 
    AND 
    (
        (
            con.createdDate >= @beginDate 
            AND con.createdDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate) 
            AND 
            (
                @description IS NULL 
                OR CAST(con.idConsumption AS VARCHAR(100)) LIKE '%' + @description + '%' 
                OR pro.description LIKE '%' + @description + '%' 
                OR sta.[name] LIKE '%' + @description + '%' 
                OR veh.economicNumber LIKE '%' + @description + '%' 
                OR veh.licensePlates LIKE '%' + @description + '%'
            ) 
            AND 
            (
                @idCardType = -1 
                OR cat.idCardType = @idCardType
            ) 
            AND 
            (
                @idProduct = pro.idProduct 
                OR @idProduct = -1
            ) 
            AND 
            (
                sta.idStation = @idStation 
                OR @idStation = -1
            ) 
            AND 
            (
                @cardCode = '-1' 
                OR 
                (
                    car.cardCode LIKE @cardCode 
                    OR car2.cardCode LIKE @cardCode
                )
            ) 
            AND 
            (
                @department IS NULL 
                OR @department = '-1'
                OR @department LIKE car.department
            ) 
            AND 
            (
                @area IS NULL 
                OR @area = '-1'
                OR @area LIKE car.area
            ) 
            AND 
            (
                coce.idCostCenter = @idCostCenter 
                OR @idCostCenter = -1
            ) 
            AND 
            (
                sec.idSection = @idSection 
                OR @idSection = -1
            ) 
            AND 
            (
                div.idDivision = @idDivision 
                OR @idDivision = -1
            ) 
            AND 
            (
                con.isManual = @isManual 
                OR @isManual = -1
            ) 
            AND @idInvoice = -1
        ) 
        OR inv.idInvoice = @idInvoice
    ) 
ORDER BY con.idConsumption
```

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure and the code you use to call it and create the data table?

Comment: IF you add WITH RECOMPILE option to the SP definition - does it help the speed?

Comment: @victor execute the store proc in SSMS check if it run faster or not. to check its tsql code or C# code?

Comment: Check this:   http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query times out when executed from web, but super-fast when executed from SSMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248112/query-times-out-when-executed-from-web-but-super-fast-when-executed-from-ssms)

Comment: how fast the `SELECT` statement run? you might want to look into the join on above code.

Comment: You really should stop littering your queries with NOLOCK everywhere. It is NOT a magic "go faster" button. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: You should also look at this article for this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/