# Executing SQL store procedure by EF Core 2.2 gets a timeout while executing it successfully in SQL Server Management

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, ef-core-2.2

I've got a strange behaviour. When I trying to execute SQL store procedure by EF Core 2.2. I get a timeout (30 seconds). But when I execute the same procedure within SQL Server Management Studio it runs successfully - it runs it about 1 or 2 sec.

**UPDATE:** This problem occured around 2 month ago. Before that the service was able to run this proc.

Here is a `DbContext` that I use:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString)
        : base(new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer(connectionString).Options)
    {
    }

    // some DbSets omitted here ...

    public async Task<string> ProcExecuteAsync(string login, string xml)
    {
        // get some data from db (omitted)

        var xmlParameter = new SqlParameter("@XML", SqlDbType.Xml) { Value = xml };
        var xmlOutputParameter = new SqlParameter("@XMLoutput", SqlDbType.Xml) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

        await Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
            "MyProc_set @idUser=@idUser,@XML=@XML,@XMLoutput=@XMLoutput OUT",
            new SqlParameter[] { userIdParameter, xmlParameter, xmlOutputParameter });

        return (string)xmlOutputParameter.Value;
    }
}
```

Then I have a handler (I use `Mediator` library):

```
public class AddToClientCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<AddToClientCommand, AddToClientResponse>
{
    private readonly IContextBuilder _contextBuilder; 

    public AddToClientCommandHandler(IContextBuilder contextBuilder)
    {
        _contextBuilder = contextBuilder;
    }

    public async Task<AddToClientResponse> Handle(AddToClientCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var context = _contextBuilder.CreateMyContext())
        {
            // getting some data from db (omitted)

            // generate xmlRequest (omitted)

            var result = await context.ProcExecuteAsync(command.Login, xmlRequest);
            return new AddToClientResponse(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a `ContextBuilder`:

```
public class ContextBuilder : IContextBuilder
{
    private readonly IOptions<ConnectionStrings> _connectionStrings;

    public ContextBuilder(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
    {
        _connectionStrings = connectionStrings;
    }

    public MyContext CreateMyContext()
    {
        var result = new MyContext(_connectionStrings.Value.Entities);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And I register it like this:

```
public static class ApplicationContextBuilderExtension
{
    public static void AddApplicationContextBuilder(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IContextBuilder, ContextBuilder>();
    }
}
```

Is it possible that the problem comes from that I use `AddSingleton` when I register `ContextBuilder`?

Can someone point me up to how and where investigate the problem?

Comment: Your handler is calling `CreateLMContext` but your builder has `CreateMyContext`. Is this just a typo/mistake in the example code?

Comment: Yes, this was a typo. Thanks, I edited it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query times out when executed from web, but super-fast when executed from SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248112/query-times-out-when-executed-from-web-but-super-fast-when-executed-from-ssms)

Comment: Can you check (from the exception stack trace or EF Core logging) if the exception is triggered by the db connection opening, or by the db command execution?

Comment: @Ivan, looks like exception is triggered by the db command execution: "ClassName": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
    "Message": "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.",

Comment: @Ivan, is there any sense to add interceptor that would add "SET ARITHABORT ON" to the executing code as it's proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248112/query-times-out-when-executed-from-web-but-super-fast-when-executed-from-ssms)? Or this is not a solution.

Comment: Well, IMHO before entering the (hard) interception path, try adding that  manually to your `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` command text and see if it has the desired positive effect.

Comment: Restarting SQL on the server helped. The question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that the problem comes from that I use AddSingleton when I register 
>   ContextBuilder?

No, as the one method in ContextBuilder is not doing db operations and is no returning the same context all the time.

> But when I execute the same procedure within SQL Server Management Studio it runs 
>   successfully

And how long does it take? To my knowledge SSMS does not impose and timeout limit, which would tell you why you do not get a timeout. EfCore is limited to 30 seconds UNLESS you CHANGE IT - which is trivial as per documentation, but it must be done.

The concept here being that SSMS is way more used for bulk operations than EfCore where a 30 second operation can be considered an error - and in those rare cases you want/need a longer timeout, reconfigure the dbcontext.

Comment: Right, EF Core has a 30 sec timeout. SSMS runs this proc just in 1 or 2 sec. So, the difference is too much. First time, this problem occured around 2 month ago. Before that the service was able to run this proc.

Comment: Well, if you have additional info you may consider next time to spend more time formulating your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue. I went through the following link:

[Stored procedure slow when called from web, fast from Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585417/stored-procedure-slow-when-called-from-web-fast-from-management-studio)

I have modified sp like this:

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc] 
    @param1 int,
AS
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = @param1

to

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc] 
    @param1 int,
AS
DECLARE @param1a int
SET @param1a = @param1
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = @param1a

For me, it is working fine.