# What could be causing slow function import performance?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, poco

I have a stored procedure that finishes execution after a few ms when I run it by itself.  However, once I import the stored procedure into EF and call it with the same exact parameters, it takes like 5 minutes to finish.  Is there some kind of setting I need to tweak or what is causing this slowness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen people have this issue when SQL Server has a bad cached execution plan. People seem to recommend running the following commands to fix it:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

See [Stored procedure slow when called from web, fast from Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585417/stored-procedure-is-very-slow-only-when-called-from-web-but-fast-if-executed-dir) for a more complete answer.

Comment: Altough you're not the author of the original answer(s), you have been straight to the point. I had the problem, and after applying these queries my SP has dropped from 2 minutes to a (normal) 5 seconds to execute properly : THANK YOU.