# Query extremely slow in code but fast in SSMS

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net-4.0, sql-server-2000

I have a fairly simple query that I keep getting timeouts (it takes over three minutes to complete, I stopped it early so I could post this question) on when it is running in code, however when I run the same query from the same computer in Sql Server Management Studio the query will only take `2532 ms` the first query when the data is not cached on the server and `524 ms` for repeated queries.

Here is my c# code

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=backend.example.com;Connect Timeout=5;Initial Catalog=Logs;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=backendAPI;Password=Redacted"))
                using (var ada = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Format(@"
SELECT [PK_JOB],[CLIENT_ID],[STATUS],[LOG_NAME],dt 
FROM [ES_HISTORY] 
inner join [es_history_dt] on [PK_JOB] = [es_historyid] 
Where client_id = @clientID and dt > @dt and (job_type > 4 {0}) {1}
Order by dt desc"
     , where.ToString(), (cbShowOnlyFailed.Checked ? "and Status = 1" : "")), conn))
{
    ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientID", ClientID);
    ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dtpFilter.Value);
    //ada.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60;
    conn.Open();
    Logs.Clear();
    ada.Fill(Logs); //Time out exception for 30 sec limit.
}
```

here is my code I am running in SSMS, I pulled it right from ada.SelectCommand.CommandText

```
declare @clientID varchar(200)
set @clientID = '138'
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '9/19/2011 12:00:00 AM'

SELECT [PK_JOB],[CLIENT_ID],[STATUS],[LOG_NAME],dt 
FROM [ES_HISTORY] 
inner join [es_history_dt] on [PK_JOB] = [es_historyid] 
Where client_id = @clientID and dt > @dt and (job_type > 4 or job_type = 0 or job_type = 1 or job_type = 4 ) 
Order by dt desc
```

What is causing the major discrepancy for the difference in time?

---

To keep the comment section clean, I will answer some FAQ's here.

The same computer and logon is used for both the application and ssms.

Only 15 rows are returned in my example query. However, `es_history` contains `11351699 rows` and `es_history_dt` contains `8588493 rows`. Both tables are well indexed and the execution plan in SSMS says they are using index seeks for the look-ups so they are fast lookups. The program is behaving as if it is not using the indexes for the C# version of the query.

Comment: Did you use the same user in SSMS as in code?

Comment: How many rows are returned by this query?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your code in SSMS is not the same code you run in your application. This line in your application adds a NVARCHAR parameter:

```
 ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientID", ClientID);
```

while in the SSMS script you declare it as VARCHAR:

```
declare @clientID varchar(200)
```

Due to the rules of [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) the `Where client_id = @clientID` expression in your query is not SARG-able where `@clientID` is of type NVARCHAR (I'm making a leap of faith and assume that `client_id` column is of type VARCHAR). The application thus forces a table scan where the SSMS query can do a quick key seek. This is a well know and understood issue with using Parameters.AddWithValue and has been discussed in many articles before, eg. see [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx). Once the problem is understood, the solutions are trivial:

- add parameters with the [constructor that accepts a type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hex23w80.aspx): `Parameters.Add("@clientID", SqlDbType.Varchar, 200)` (and **do** pass in the explicit length to prevent cache pollution, see [Query performance and plan cache issues when parameter length not specified correctly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/10/05/query-performance-and-plan-cache-issues-when-parameter-length-not-specified-correctly.aspx)
- *or* cast the parameter in the SQL text: `where client_id = cast(@clientID as varchar(200))`.

The first solution is superior because it solves the cache pollution problem in addition to the SARG-ability problem.

I would also recommend you read [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Actually I used varchar because the interface for the function passed the client ID as a string. I checked the schema and Client_ID is actually a int. Changing it in my code to convert the passed string to a int before executing the query solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585417/stored-procedure-slow-when-called-from-web-fast-from-management-studio), just to make sure the problem isn't due to a stale query execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue:

- Call Stored procedure from code: 30 seconds+
- Call Same Stored procedure from SSMS: milliseconds.
- Call SQL from within stored procedure from code: milliseconds.

***Solution***:
Drop Stored Procedure, then recreate exactly the same stored procedure, now both returning in milliseconds. No code change.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32109925)

Comment: This has worked well for me in the past, but today when I did it, it started running slowly in both :(

Answer (score 0):

Run the profiler on your c# connection - there may be other activity going on that you are not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the execution plan from both SSMS when you manually run your query and then from Profiler when you are running your application.  Compare and contrast.