# ADO.NET timeout but works fine in SSMS

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I'm trying to run a query from ADO.NET using SQL Server 2008R2. I'm using a CTE to provide paging and adding parameters for `@Offset` and `@Limit`, which are both integers.

I'm building up a parameterized query depending on user inputs. The final output is this:

```
;WITH Results_CTE AS (
    SELECT  ld.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Key_Field) AS RowNum  
    FROM list..List_Data ld 
    WHERE VALUE_2010 IS NOT NULL  
    AND  Postcode LIKE @Postcode + '%' 
) SELECT * FROM Results_CTE 
    WHERE RowNum > @Offset AND RowNum < @Offset + @Limit 
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

I'm using a few like clauses which is why I have `OPTION RECOMPILE`. If I declare the parameters via SSMS and run like so:

```
declare @postcode varchar(10) = 'SW1 1AA';
declare @Offset int = 0;
declare @Limit int = 10;
```

I get a very quick response time (less than 1s). If I try this with ADO.NET, however, it takes forever. I've tried adding the parameters with both of these:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Offset", startRowIndex) // times out
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Limit", limit)

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Offset", SqlDbType.BigInt)) // also times out
cmd.Parameters.Item("@Offset").Value = startRowIndex
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Limit", SqlDbType.BigInt))
cmd.Parameters.Item("@Limit").Value = limit
```

If there are only a few rows returned by the first query though and I drop the `@Offset` and `@Limit` filtering, I get a decent response time. Is there a way I can speed this up *and* use paging?

EDIT: I'm passing in the `@postcode` parameter (which is a string in .NET via this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", normalizedPostcode)
```

Comment: @close voter. This isn't a dupe. The previous question was about explaining different behaviour with variables not parameters. The two are treated differently by SQL Server.

Comment: Can you show the code where you pass in the `@postcode` parameter?

Comment: Is it definitely the SQL timing out? There is no possibility that its timing out trying to get a connection (eg because you have loads of connections open still when you do this) or anything else like that?

Comment: If I remove the clauses for the `Offset` and `Limit` in .NET it works every time, but only for small data sets.

Comment: Interesting; not really an answer, but one common thing to try is looking at differences between the two usages; for example, SSMS normally has different `SET` options (which can render some indexes useless), or different isolation-level, etc. Also, have you tried [`OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature.aspx) rather than `RECOMPILE` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ADO.NET code is passing in a parameter of [a different datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637907/query-extremely-slow-in-code-but-fast-in-ssms/7638059#7638059) than the one you are testing in SSMS and you are getting implicit cast issues.

Don't use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", normalizedPostcode)
```

as this will auto create an `nvarchar` parameter and you will be getting implicit casts in your execution plan meaning that an index cannot be used. Instead pass in an explicitly created parameter of `varchar` type instead.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@postcode", SqlDbType.Varchar, 10)
```

Comment: Excellent tip. Exactly tuning the parameters in .NET to the DBType gets more or less instant response.

Answer (score 2):

1) For @postcode parameter [please specify the length](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/10/05/query-performance-and-plan-cache-issues-when-parameter-length-not-specified-correctly.aspx).

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@postcode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = str`

2) Rewrite the query:

```
;WITH Results_CTE AS (
    SELECT  ld.Key_Field, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Key_Field) AS RowNum  
    FROM list..List_Data ld 
    WHERE VALUE_2010 IS NOT NULL  
    AND  Postcode LIKE @Postcode + '%' 
) SELECT * FROM Results_CTE a
INNER JOIN list..List_Data b ON a.Key_Field = Key_Field
WHERE RowNum > @Offset AND RowNum < @Offset + @Limit 
--OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

**Note 1**: I assume that `Key_Field` is primary key (clustered) for `List_Data` table.

**Note 2**: Check if you have an index on VALUE_2010 and Postcode fields. If you have SQL 2008+ then you can create an filtered index:

```
--UNIQUE if Postcode has unique values for VALUE_2010 IS NOT NULL
CREATE [UNIQUE] INDEX aaa
ON MySchema.List_Data (Postcode)
WHERE VALUE_2010 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This seems to improve speed by a few milliseconds, but it varies. Can't hurt for good measure.