# Why is there a timeout in a simple select

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlexception

I have an application which uses `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` to read data from a SQL Server 2008 database. When I use this, I will get a `TimeoutException`. The `CommandTimeout` is set to 40s - it takes also 40s till the exception occurs. I have also set the `IsolationLevel` to `ReadUncommitted`.
When I execute the query directly in SQL Server Management Studio, it will be executed fast (1s) without any problems.

The query is relatively simple:

```sql
select TOP (50)  * 
from ActivityView('de') a 
where IsTrashed = 0 and 
   (Subject Like '%' and 
            (a.InchargeId = 'e9584e24-090a-4ef3-a048-330399bfb1b0' or a.PrivilegeLevelId in ('eb39d6bf-4904-4b8d-942f-39463c5d3c3f') or 
            (select top 1 Id from ActivityContact x where x.ActivityId = a.Id and x.UserId = '61423b82-bd6a-4381-808a-6df42f02ab59' ) is not null)) 
 order by a.[Key] desc
```

When I execute this, I get the fallowing exception:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.SetMetaData(_SqlMetaDataSet metaData, Boolean moreInfo)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

But when I execute the statements directly in SQL Server Management Studio, it is working perfectly with no error.

Comment: A lot depends on what the function `ActivityView('de')` is doing.  Does a select on `select * from ActivityView('de')` also time out?

Comment: Mmhh - I haven't tested this. But why is there a timeout with my app and why is it very fast directly in Management-Studio? - I mean, the timeout is occuring after the command is executed on sql server and it comes not back after 40s. Isn't this part of executing the same as it is with Management Studio?

Comment: ActivityView('de') is a simple view which uses 'de' as a part of a join.

Comment: I'm sorry to see that you are using GUIDs for ids.

Comment: In your database are those guids being stored as `uniqueidentifiers` or as strings (`varchar`, `char`, `nvarchar`, ect.)? If they are, and you are using parameteriezed queries and passing in `Guid` objects you may be getting bit by [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) (which has [gotten me in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637907/query-extremely-slow-in-code-but-fast-in-ssms))promoting the text in the datatable to a `uniqueidentifier` and not using your indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since you have a SQL-command that is constructed based on what the user selects as filters you need to generate a more efficient SQL command based on those selections**

So if the user did not select a `Subject`, dont use `Subject Like '%'` just dont include that in your query. Keep in mind that any record in your table will match that condition and the LIKE operator is very time consuming

Apply this idea, of just including the filters that have some criteria, to all the posible filters that your command can have.

Comment: Hi Mauricio - Subject Like '%' is in the query, because the user doesn't give in a searchvalue - I think, sql server (the optimizer) will remove it?

Comment: Yes, the SQL command is based on user filters - there can be more as one value for PrivilegeLevelId

Comment: @ThomasKehl I have updated my answer based on your comments. basically if the user did not select any criteria for a filter dont include it in your query

Comment: Also, there is no LINQ-to-SQL in the question or in the stack trace.

Comment: @siride thanks for pointing that out, if you have an answer feel free to post it

Comment: @MauricioGracia: I don't, unfortunately, though I had some ideas that didn't pan out.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause of TimeOut Exception is very strange.

I create and open a `SqlConnection` each time a query is executed. However, I don't call `connection.Dispose()` at the end of query (although I call `connection.Close()`). When I restart the SQL Server instance service the error disappears, but after few executions, the error is back again.

I added `connection.Dispose()` to the end of query and everything worked fine.