# using the literal '@' with variable within the string

Tags: c#

I am trying to write an SQL statement as string literal with two variables as follows-

```
String str="abc"; int val=123;
String sql=@"SELECT Column1, Column2 
             FROM Table
             WHERE Column1= '"" + str + ""' AND Column2 > "" + val + ""
             ORDER BY Column1";
```

But those variables are not treated as variables.  Any help?

UPDATE:
Added screenshot with order by clause. There are red curly underlines.
[image]

Comment: You need to rewrite your sql using paramertized queries

Comment: Those variables are treated as variables? Do you mean treated as strings?

Comment: change to WHERE Column1= '" + str + "' AND Column2 > " + val; but i would suggest you use WHERE Column1= @str AND Column2 > @val" and then user command parameters.

Comment: @frenchie There's no need to use LINQ for that (although it's possible). Passing user-supplied data through parameters is generally sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would rewrite the query to use parameterized queries. You will likely have better performance under load and you prevent SQL Injection if the string you are entering comes from user enterable values.

```
String sql=@"SELECT Column1, Column2 
             FROM Table
             WHERE Column1 = @str AND Column2 > @val
             ORDER BY Column1";

using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)
using(var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.Add("@str", SqlDbType.NVarChar, Column1MaxTextLength).Value = str;
    command.Parameters.Add("@val", SqlDbType.Int).Value = val;

    using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

EDIT: To address your screenshot, you need another @ symbol before the last set of quotes.

```
String sql=@"SELECT Column1, Column2 
             FROM Table                                       
             WHERE Column1= '" + str + "' AND Column2 > " + val + @"
             ORDER BY Column1";                               //  ^-- You are missing this guy
```

But I still think you should re-write to use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 3):

First of all try using parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection. You may read more [**here**](http://www.lavamunky.com/2011/11/why-parameterized-queries-stop-sql.html).

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM Table WHERE Column1=@col1 AND Column2 > @col2 ORDER BY Column1, Column2 " , conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", str);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", val);
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //...
        }            
    }
}
```

But to answer your issue:

```
String str="abc"; 
int val=123;
String sql=@"SELECT Column1, Column2 
             FROM Table
             WHERE Column1= '" + str + "' AND Column2 > " + val + "";
```

Or you could use String.Format as suggested by `Aron`

```
String str="abc"; 
int val=123;
String sql=String.Format(@"SELECT Column1, Column2 
             FROM Table
             WHERE Column1= '{0}' AND Column2 > {1}",str,val);
```

Comment: You don't need to call `ToString()` on `val`.

Comment: If i want to use order by clause at the end? see the updated question.

Comment: @SKPaul just add it at the end of your command as you would in a normal query.

Comment: +1 for both explaining where the OP went wrong and showing the better solution, I would like to see the words SQL Injection in your answer somewhere though!

Comment: I always liked using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Add(` instead of `AddWithValue` that way you can be more explicit on the data type of the declared variable. I have gotten [bitten in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637907/query-extremely-slow-in-code-but-fast-in-ssms) where a unexpected cast causes the database not to use the indexes you expected it to use.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you mean when `string` gets cast to `nvarchar` and a widening operator is implicitly applied to the the table side of the query plan, resulting in the index being by passed? I am sure that has NEVER happened to me...>_<

Comment: @Aron thanks, i edited my answer to also provide this example.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the tip. I won't change my answer though, as you have already covered this on yours. I `stole` your reader part already :-). I had the `ExecuteNonQuery` that would make no sense...

Answer (score 0):

```
        String str = "abc"; int val = 123;
        StringBuilder strbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strbuilder.Append("SELECT Column1, Column2  FROM Table WHERE Column1=");
        strbuilder.Append("'" + str + "'");
        strbuilder.Append(" AND Column2 >");
        strbuilder.Append("'" + val.ToString() + "'");
```

user string builder may this helps you.

Comment: I don't want to use StringBuilder. That is not my problem.

Comment: ok. you can try "Scott Chamberlain" answer.without using sqlinjection.