# Difference between results of calls stored procedure from MS SQL SERVER and MS ACCESS

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012, adodb, ms-access-2003

SP is RecordSource of the form. 
When form is opened SP executed and after a time-out of query, connection is closing with nothing. 
If SP executed from SSMS it performed for about 2 seconds and returns a set of records. 
As I watched through the SSMS Profiler calls are identical, but count of Reads value (an execute from Access) > 28 million, and about 70 thousand from the SSMS.
Help me, I'm confused.
Screen with profiler
http://take.ms/u7tTy

Comment: Just a guess here: Count of Reads != Count of Rows. Could be an issue with bad query plans for the SP causing this, such as parameter sniffing.

Comment: @BIDeveloper,
28 million reads from Access

Comment: `Could be an issue with bad query plans for the SP causing this, such as parameter sniffing.`
@tobypls,
what does it mean?

Comment: @anatol have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585417/stored-procedure-slow-when-called-from-web-fast-from-management-studio (web in this case is similar to MS Access in your case)

Comment: It would help if you post a screen picture of the SQL Server Profiler output.

Comment: @richard345, 
I have no reputation to posting images. Get link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tobypls,
thank you very much - your link was helpful.
Simple solution is rewrite (for example)

from

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc] 
@param1 int,  
AS  
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = @param1
```

to

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc] 
@param1 int,
AS
DECLARE @param1a int
SET @param1a = @param1
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = @param1a
```

I get it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13823047/4269118).

But if you need full understanding of trouble then you must read really great article
[Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)