# Which could be the cause of a slower connection (on localhost) to the online DB?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I really don't know how it is possible. Connection from my SQL Express to the online database and doing query/etc is it so fast.

But, running the web application on localhost to the online DB takes very long time. Such as 20-30 seconds for a simple request. Watching the website online is so fast. So there aren't problem with the main application.

Connection string such as :

```
<add key="ConnectionString_ONLINE" value="data source=95.40.100.200,1900;initial catalog=DBName;USER ID=Username;Password=Password;" />
```

What could be the main cause?

Comment: Try enabling trace for your aspx page and see which component is taking longer time.

Comment: Are you sure the connection to the remote server isn't slow itself?

Comment: Yes! As I wrote, watching the website online it take only some ms...

Comment: Maybe it is caused by the differences between the online and local hardware and on the SQL server edition. The query is executed on the Sql Server, I suggest to focus on the Sql Server not on the web site. Try to execute the same query (that causes the problem) directly to both Sql Servers.

Comment: Yeah, I've done it! the time is quite the same, in the order of ms!

Comment: Please see this SO answer, as it may answer your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250713/sqldataadapter-fill-method-slow/250961#250961

Answer (score 1):

I realise this was asked quite some time ago, but for the sake of future searches I thought I'd add this...

I also had issues with a horribly slow connection on localhost SQL compared to a live SQL server box.  Even over VPN it was quicker than my own localhost.  I eventually realised that every time I was running the application on localhost, it was directly through Visual Studio which added it's own debugging overheads in some way.  When I compiled the application and ran the EXE externally, I got faster speeds.

Just worth mentioning!