# SQL Stored Procedure VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql, parameters

I have a Stored Procedure which when run on SQLServer takes 1 second to run, yet in my VB.Net code it takes nearly 20 seconds. It takes a long time on the line:

```
Adapter.Fill(ds,"TimeTable")
```

Am I doing something wrong for it to take so long?

My code snippet is below:

```
    SQLConn = New SqlConnection(SQLDConnString)
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SPNAME", SQLConn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    SQLConn.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", p1)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", p2)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", p3)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", p4)
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
    adapter.Fill(ds, "TimeTable")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("TimeTable")
    SQLConn.Close()
```

Comment: Is this on the loopback or across networks?

Comment: not sure what you mean sorry Grant

Comment: When you do `Adapter.Fill(ds,"TimeTable")`, you are doing more than just running the sproc - you are also transferring *all the results* from the server to the client. How much data are we talking about here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250713/sqldataadapter-fill-method-slow

Comment: the sproc returns 28 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to find a fix to this by declaring local variables in my SP and then assigning my Parameters to these variables.

Something to do with parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

If your datagridview property for column and row height/width is set to auto, it can take a lot of time to finish the procedure.  I had this happen once, where a stored procedure took an abnormally large amount of time and it ended up being that property that was causing it to stall.