# Reading Huge Data Using SQL Stored Procedure and C# (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a requirement to pull huge data from SQL Server 2005 database for reporting purpose. Our stored procedure is returning more than 15,000 rows.

When I call the procedure from the application (MVC 4.0) the request is timing out!!! (May be because of the data size)

Is there is any best practice to read such a huge data from SQL Server 2005 database using 
MVC 4.0 Application???

Comment: Nope we need to display all the rows in a single report and export to excel

Comment: 1) Review the stored procedure to see if there are any optimizations you can make, 2) Move the processing of the data for the report to the MVC app, having the stored procedure return simply the data, 3) increase the timeout on the connection (options listed in order of preference).

Comment: `SqlDataReader` receives one line at time from database.
Using `<table style="table-layout: fixed">` can improve rendering time.

Comment: Increase your command timeout with SqlCommand.CommandTimeout

Comment: set your .CommandTimeout=0;

Comment: 15,000 rows is actually not that many. Have you tried running the stored procedure from within management studio to see if it returns quickly?

Comment: Why don't you post your SP and also inform us about any indexes you had on your table 15k is not a very big number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i faced the same problem, but i was about to render more than 1,48,000 records. So the solution for this is using multithreading. You will be having one method which fetches the data from database, call that particular method in a seperate thread. Your data will be loaded in less than 5 seconds. Multithreading has been introduced only to manipulate large number of data without lagging performance.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing a timeout because your SQL query takes a long time to finish. This is not due to the size of the result (15,000 records is not a huge amount of data), but because the query runs inefficiently.

Maybe you're missing a couple of indices, maybe the stored procedure is written the wrong way - it's impossible to know from here. Try optimizing your query or database (if you have a DBA available, they can help. If not, the Management Studio can have some tips for you).

If you can't optimize the query or the database, you're left with increasing the time out, as others suggested.

Comment: You are right, 15,000 is really not that much. definitly nothing to call "huge".

Answer (score 0):

First Que is why you are not using Dataset and Data source view in the Reporting(If its reporting in SQL server).

If its not Reporting Services and you only want to use C# code then try to make some helper function for it.

see here for the timeout option 
[http://forums.asp.net/t/1040377.aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974/query-times-out-from-web-app-but-runs-fine-from-management-studio)

and also here for optimising the code and SP
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974/query-times-out-from-web-app-but-runs-fine-from-management-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple tips on how you can use to optimize this:

Optimize query – see if you can optimize your query in some way. Add indices to your tables, check where statements and such..  I can’t really give you any specific recommendations w/o seeing the query and knowing the schema. See what others have already suggested on this topic.

Limit the amount of data stored procedure is returning – my guess is that MVC app doesn’t really need all 15k rows but a lot more. Check out this post: [efficient way to implement paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548475/efficient-way-to-implement-paging) . This will not speed up the query so much but it will make the app more efficient.